# pyinstaller empty dist folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I convert a python file to an excel file, I find the `dist` folder is empty

plz what can I do

if their another way to make that happen

this is on my pc, I try to do that in other pc it works but the antivirus detect my script as a virus

```
C:\Users\lilo\Documents\audiobook-master>pyinstaller --onefile main.py
102 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.1
102 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
103 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
104 INFO: wrote C:\Users\lilo\Documents\audiobook-master\main.spec
106 INFO: UPX is not available.
108 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\Users\lilo\Documents\audiobook-master',
'C:\Users\lilo\Documents\audiobook-master']
```

Comment: do you mean `.exe file ` instead of `excel file` ?

Comment: ah sorry for that, I mean exe life

Answer (score 0):

*UPX is not available.*

https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/

download the upx file and copy into the same folder which pyinstaller.exe exists